# undo/redo with sagas/redux (pt 2)

Tags: redux, undo, immutable.js, redux-saga

Using Redux and Immutable, just incorporated Sagas into the API layer, but now trying to tackle undo/redo with server persistence

**Constraints:**

1. Assume a max undo/redo stack of 2
2. State tree is very large. Having copies of the state tree living in past/present is not desirable.

**Assumption**: After adding 1 item to the tree, I'm assuming that 100 items in present tree will now become 101 in present and 100 in past. I know that immutableJS does have structural sharing, but not sure if this is true

**My approach thus far**:

Three data structures: PENDING, CURRENT, FUTURE

1. Using Saga middleware, append "TRANSACTION START" to dispatched action
2. Wrap data reducer in undoable library (or similar), filter for all actions with "TRANSACTION_START", hold in PENDING stack. Saga has called POST in the meantime.
3. TRANSACTION_SUCCESS fires when POST completes, Sagas will retry 3x before throwing TRANSACTION_FAIL.
4. On TRANSACTION_FAIL, remove from PENDING stack (in reducer) and throw error. Since stack is small, I don't mind iterating through to throw it out.
5. Merge PENDING and CURRENT for the optimistic state tree
6. Once PENDING size > 2 (from more ADDs) && bottom item in stack marked COMPLETE, move bottom (think a dequeue) into CURRENT.
7. On dispatch of UNDO, pop from PENDING stack and store in FUTURE, cancel POST, re-render state.

References: 
Saga Recipe

http://yelouafi.github.io/redux-saga/docs/recipes/index.html

This library for immutable structures + undo/redo

https://github.com/dairyisscary/redux-undo-immutable
(7 months since last update so using it as a guide)

I've seen the implementation of a commandSaga with RxJS, but that's not feasible given our current team.

https://github.com/salsita/redux-saga-rxjs/blob/master/examples/undo-redo-optimistic/src/sagas/commandSaga.js

Questions:

1. Am I on the right track?
2. This [code](https://gist.github.com/CptLemming/d9e65e38b1e2091ae4dd) uses a command class, but it does not address server-side updating. Is using Sagas unnecessary?

Sanity check?

Comment: Unless the data *difference* between two states is huge, there's no reason to worry about storing many state trees. They share anything that didn't change so it takes up near 0 memory.

Comment: Makes sense. What about handling optimistic updating? What if a user fires "UNDO" before it is resolved with the server? I figure that I'd have the saga generated race between UNDO and Transaction_Resolved